# Insufficient memory

Tags: ram

I have a 4.2.1 android version phone. In internal storage there is 114 MB free space but I cannot download or update any app because I get an error saying "insufficient memory in internal storage". I tried all the first aid listed in this site but no gain :( .

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning cache/junk and unused apps first https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard